# m getting error from from recylerview because m trying to get data from sqlite and set into recylerview

Tags: java

> 09-06 15:12:57.845 25003-25003/enkay.ntucsingapoor E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: enkay.ntucsingapoor, PID: 25003
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{enkay.ntucsingapoor/enkay.ntucsingapoor.Activity.BabyDiapers}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                            at
>   enkay.ntucsingapoor.Activity.BabyDiapers.onCreate(BabyDiapers.java:55)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>
> Here IS My Xml File MArket_Recyler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyler_data"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> this is my another xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_baby_diapers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorNavIcon"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="enkay.ntucsingapoor.Activity.BabyDiapers">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Search Bar"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <Button
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="279dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO"
            android:background="@color/Yellow"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="111dp">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/List_items"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

In your setContentView,

change R.layout.activity_baby diapers to R.layout.baby_diapers. And Paste both your xmls here in the question, like item xml and mainactivity xml

That's it